# How do I configure the TortoiseSVN 'Global ignore pattern' properly?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnignore

I would like TortoiseSVN (1.5.3) to ignore certain folders, their contents and certain other files wherever they might appear in my directory hierarchy but I cannot get the global ignore string right.

Whatever I do, it either adds to much or ignores too much

What is the correct 'Global ignore pattern' to ignore....

```
Folders : bin obj release compile 
Files   : *.bak *.user *.suo
```

Update: To help clarify... yes I am using this on windows.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Currently I have the following in my Global Ignore Pattern:

```
bin obj CVS .cvsignore *.user *.suo Debug Release *.pdb test.* Thumbs.db
```

Works really well to ignore several hidden or temp files/folders....

So for your specific requirements:

- Folders: `bin obj release compile`
- Files: `*.bak *.user *.suo`

I would use:

```
bin obj release compile *.bak *.user *.suo
```

Comment: I found I had to add additional items for Initial Caps variations, but this works well.

Answer (score 6):

(Adding to an old question..)
It depends mainly on your language. So there are some versions here already for VB6 and others.

This is for **Visual Studio & C#**:

```
global-ignores = *.suo *.user *.userosscache *.sln.docstates *.userprefs debug release Debug Release bin x64 x86 obj Obj *_i.c *_p.c *_i.h *.ilk *.meta *.obj *.pch *.pdb *.pgc *.pgd *.rsp *.sbr *.tlb *.tli *.tlh *.tmp *.tmp_proj *.log *.psess *.vsp *.vspx *.sap Thumbs.db _UpgradeReport_Files *.dbmdl
```

and goes into your

```
%APPDATA%/Subversion/config
```

file. If you have a fresh *config* file, like me, you will only find *global-ignore* entries that are commented out, so you can append the line.

It is take mainly from the gitignore at https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore .

**General case for any language**
Basically, googling (or binging, if you so desire) for "gitignore (language or tool)" you will find sample gitignore files, the syntax is similar to the *global-ignore* of SVN, you just need to do some editing (all entries in one line for SVN, each entry in new line for GIT).

A good text editor like [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/) or [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)  helps a lot when converting.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Windows don't you need to use an ignore pattern like this:

*/bin */obj

for directories? And maybe even:

```
*/bin/* */obj/*
```

I must admit I only realised this after I had committed the wrong things, so I haven't tried this out 'live'. Notice the use of the forward slashes in the directory pattern.

(See this link for the source:
http://svn.haxx.se/tsvnusers/archive-2007-03/0281.shtml
)

Answer (score 3):

Please be aware that using the subversion 1.7+ does not expect paths in the Global Ignore List (the global-ignores line in the %appdata%\subversion\config file). See http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html

So, to ignore bin and obj directories in *all* projects:
global-ignores = bin obj

Answer (score 2):

This is one I use for .NET. Note that I use VB6 as well as other packages so there are extra entries. Also it is case sensitive.

*.chm *.dat *.dll *.ini *.err *.exe *.DLL *.INI *.ERR *.EXE *.backup *.zip *.ZIP *.vbw *.scc *.vbg *.log *.exp *.lib *.vrs*.SCC *.PRF *.prf *.NIP *.NOP *.nip *.nop *.out *.bjob *.job *.prt *.tmp *.txt *.EX_ *.ex_ *.MDP *.bak *.BAK *.CFG *.cfg *.TXT *.vrs *.VRS *.scc *.SCC *.vsc *.VSC *.mdb *.MDB *.cur *.oca *.setup *.png *.suo *.user Debug Release bin *.pdb *.trx TestResults *.WS~ *.ocx

These three proved critical in greatly reducing the number of files wildcards I had to track down.

Debug Release bin

Comment: Personally as a web developer I would include image files in source control - they are updated regularly and required in source control to ensure visual version consistency

Comment: I would not use dll and pdb, since you would want to commit third party libraries you include in your projects.