# How do I unversion a folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to figure out how to unversion the bin and obj files in my porject and I'm struggling.

I've found various instructions telling me to export the files onto themselves but that just ends up with the folders being "obstructed" in TSVN's 'view mods' screen, and it locks up the whole check out - I get errors saying that ..../bin is not a working copy.

I also at one point just deleted the folders from the repos but the when they get re-created in the next build they show up as the ? symbol which is kinda annoying.

Help?

Comment: Yes, deleting them from the repo is how you unversion them. The annoying `?` files can easily be hidden. See the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them to the svn ignore list. Instructions can be found [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html)

And perhaps just read [this question solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182492/how-do-i-configure-the-tortoisesvn-global-ignore-pattern-properly)

Comment: Ahh, you need to delete them AND set them to ignore in the same action.
If you delete them first then try to ignore them later, it has a hissy fit about them not have working copy areas (.svn files)

Answer (score 5):

In the latest SVN (1.7.10), if you have TortoiseSVN Installed (1.7.13), there is an option in the right click menu, "Unversion and Add to ignore list".

[image]

This really ads the files/folders to ignore list. The hidden .svn folder still exists in the folder. **Note that you have to execute commit after this action, which asks to delete these files but they are only unversioned.**

Answer (score 1):

Go to TortoiseSVN Settings / General and add `bin obj` to 'Global ignore pattern' - it will exclude all your `bin` and `obj` folders. You can add certain file extensions, ie. `*.suo`